# Объявленная переменная умерла?

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Вот,собственно вопрос про С++: объявил в первом цикле for переменную инт, а во втором цикле IDE ее не видит и выдает ошибку, мол она не объявлена? Наводит на мысль, что это не баг, а фича. Так и должно быть? Объявленная в цикле переменная видна только для этого цикла?
[image: Скриншот с ошибкой]

Comment: скорее да, чем нет. Но точный ответ по стандарту не скажу)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно описанию for-предложения в стандарте C++ (6.5.3 The for statement)

> 1 The for statement

```
for ( for-init-statement conditionopt; expressionopt) statement
```

> is equivalent to

```
{ 
    for-init-statement 
    while ( condition ) 
    { 
       statement expression ; 
    } 
}
```

> except that **names declared in the for-init-statement are in the same
>   declarative region as those declared in the condition**, and except that
>   a continue in statement (not enclosed in another iteration statement)
>   will execute expression before re-evaluating condition. [Note: Thus
>   the ﬁrst statement speciﬁes initialization for the loop; the condition
>   (6.4) speciﬁes a test, made before each iteration, such that the loop
>   is exited when the condition becomes false; the expression often
>   speciﬁes incrementing that is done after each iteration. —end note]

Поэтому ваше предложение `for` можно представить, как это описано в стандарте

```
{    // блок кода, в котором объявлена переменная i      
    int i = 0;

    { 
        while ( i < 10; )
        {
            massiv[i] = i;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

// здесь уже нет доступа к переменной `i` в виду прекращения ее существования.
```

После выхода из предложения `for` переменная прекращает свое существование, и соответствующее имя становится необъявленным.

Answer (score 3):

Переменные в С++ видны в пределах того блока, в котором они объявлены. В вашем случае i объявлена в блоке for, и следовательно, видна только в нем.
Второй блок for пытается присвоить i значение 0, когда переменной i уже нету. В каждом блоке заново объявляйте переменную.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7;++i)
       //здесь i есть
       ++i;
 //А здесь нету
  i = 0; //ошибка
```